# fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

Tags: c++

I recently started C/C++ programming in school (less than 2 months ago), so I have no idea what I'm doing.

From my code I have received these error messages:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl MyRand(double,double)" (?MyRand@@YANNN@Z) referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl love_code(void)" (?love_code@@YAHXZ) referenced in function _main
fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

I have seen similar questions to mine on this site, but none of the solutions provided worked for me. How can I fix this error?

Pictures provided of the original code and what the output should look like, if anyone wants to know.
[image]
[image]

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

double length (double x1, double y1, double z1, double x2, double y2, double z2);
double squares (double x);
double MyRand ( double a, double b);
int love_code();

int main()
{

char name[20], parent[15];
strcpy_s(name, "Susan McLeod");
strcpy_s(parent, "Bernice McLeod"); 
int i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, i10, i11, i12, i13;
i2 = name[0], i3 = name[1], i4 = name[2], i5 = name[3], i12 = name[4], i13 = name[5];
i6 =parent[0], i7=parent[1], i8=parent[2], i9=parent[3], i10=parent[4], i11=parent[5];
cout << "The ASCII code of [" << name << "] are " <<'['<< i2 <<']'<<'['<< i3 <<']'<<'['<< i4 <<']'<<'['<< i5 <<']'<<'['<< i12 <<']'<<'['<< i13 <<']'<< endl;
cout << "The ASCII code of [" << parent << "] are " <<'['<< i6 <<']'<<'['<< i7 <<']'<<'['<< i8 <<']'<<'[' << i9 <<']'<<'['<< i10 <<']'<<'['<< i11 <<']'<< endl;


int j, love, txtcode, shift, len;
FILE *f1, *f2, *f3;
char txt [5000];


love = love_code();
cout << "The love code is [" << love << ']' << endl;
srand (love);


fopen_s(&f1, "letter.txt", "r");
fopen_s(&f2, "hw_04_code.txt", "w");
fopen_s(&f3, "hw_03_code.txt", "w");

if (f1 == NULL) printf ("Cannot open file - letter.txt\n");
if (f2 == NULL) printf ("Cannot open file - hw_04_code.txt\n");
if (f3 == NULL) printf ("Cannot open file - hw_03_code.txt\n");


j = 0;
while (fscanf_s (f1, "%c", &txt [j]) !=EOF)

{
shift = (int) (MyRand (0, 6));
txtcode = txt [j] << shift;
fprintf (f3, "%10d\n", txt [j]);
//fprintf (f2, "%10d, %10d\n", txtcode, shift)
fprintf (f2, "%10d\n", txtcode);
j++;
}

txt [j] = '\0';
len = strlen (txt);
printf ("The total number of characters are %d\n", len);


fclose (f1);
fclose (f2);
fclose (f3);
return (0);
}

//return random number between a and b

double MyRand ( double a, double b);
{
return ((b - a + 1) * rand() / (double) RAND_MAX + a);
}
```

Comment: In the implementation of `MyRand`: `double MyRand ( double a, double b);<--semicolon of doom`

Comment: Your use of [`fscanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ybhk9kc.aspx) is incorrect. For format types `%c` and `%s` it requires a **size** argument as well as the target pointer. Please enable compiler warnings. *"The main difference between the more secure functions (that have the _s suffix) and the other versions is that the more secure functions require the size in characters of each c, C, s, S, and [ type field to be passed as an argument immediately following the variable. "*

Comment: only decleration of `love_code()` exists. Write implementation of this.

Comment: ... although my problem with those supposedly "more secure" functions is that if you omit the required size arguments, and ignore the compiler warnings, that are **more** dangerous than the original versions.

Answer (score 0):

This statement does not create a function but another function declaration

```
double MyRand ( double a, double b); // ; <- terminates the statement creates a declaration

{
 return ((b - a + 1) * rand() / (double) RAND_MAX + a);
}
```

Since compiler cannot find a declared function it gives you the error.
Remove -> `;` at the end of double `MyRand ( double a, double b)`  and the compiler will not complain about unresolved `MyRand(double,double)` external.